# Argument name matching for multipart data in Micronaut not working correctly with Google Functions

Tags: java, google-cloud-functions, micronaut

I am working on a Micronaut Google Cloud Function project and am having trouble getting it to recognize a multipart data upload. The smallest reproducible case is:

```
package example.test;

import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse;
import io.micronaut.http.MediaType;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller;
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Post;
import io.micronaut.http.multipart.CompletedFileUpload;

import java.io.IOException;

@Controller
public class UploadController {
    @Post(uri = "/upload", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA}, produces = {MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public HttpResponse<?> otherUpload(CompletedFileUpload cfu) throws IOException {
        return HttpResponse.ok(cfu.getBytes().length);
    }
}
```

Running this with the `:runFunction` gradle call it boots correctly:

```
Task :runFunction
15:59:12.757 [main] INFO  i.m.c.DefaultApplicationContext$RuntimeConfiguredEnvironment - Established active environments: [function, gcp]
15:59:12.866 [main] INFO  i.m.gcp.function.http.HttpFunction - Initialized function in: 106ms
2024-02-04 15:59:12.149:INFO::main: Logging initialized @239ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2024-02-04 15:59:12.992:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.26.v20200117; built: 2020-01-17T12:35:33.676Z; git: 7b38981d25d14afb4a12ff1f2596756144edf695; jvm 17.0.10+7
2024-02-04 15:59:13.017:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@34625ccd{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2024-02-04 15:59:13.039:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@290dbf45{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2024-02-04 15:59:13.039:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1133ms
Feb 04, 2024 3:59:13 PM com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker logServerInfo
INFO: Serving function...
Feb 04, 2024 3:59:13 PM com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker logServerInfo
INFO: Function: io.micronaut.gcp.function.http.HttpFunction
Feb 04, 2024 3:59:13 PM com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker logServerInfo
INFO: URL: http://localhost:8080/
```

However, it fails with a simple curl request:

```
 curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/upload' \
      --form 'cfu=@"/Users/me/test_document.txt"'
```

Which results in:

```
{
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "_embedded": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Required argument [CompletedFileUpload cfu] not specified",
                "path": "/cfu"
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/upload",
            "templated": false
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried everything to make this work including `@Part("cfu")` explicitly set on the argument. No matter what I do I can't get this to function correctly.

Am I doing something wrong? I am on Micronaut `4.2.4` and Java 17.